# Django Formset has only one form with data, remaining have empty data

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, formsets

I'm using Django Formsets to have multiple forms.
Initially I have only one form, and I add more forms using JavaScript dynamically.
When I submit this form,  request.POST object has only the data for the first form.
Incidentally, if I set formset to show two initial forms and submit , it has both.
The problem happens when I append new ones using javaScript

```
//forms.py
from django import forms

class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
email = forms.EmailField()
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


//views.py (this one to handle the get)
if request.method == 'GET':
    add_user_formset = formset_factory(AddUserForm, extra=1, max_num=6)
    context['add_user_formset'] = add_user_formset

//view.py (this one to handle the post of the form)
@login_required(login_url = reverse_lazy('login') )
def add_users(request, ir_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = formset_factory(AddUserForm)
        my_formset = my_form(request.POST)

        if my_formset.is_valid():
            for form in my_formset:
                if form.is_valid():
                    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                    username = form.cleaned_data['email']
                    first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                    last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                    password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
                    user = User(email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,username=username)
                    user.set_password(password)
                    user.save()
                    new_user_profile =  UserProfile.objects.get(id=user.id)
                    new_user_profile.user_role = users_role[0][0]
                    new_user_profile.save()
                    ir_obj = IR.objects.get(ir_id=int(ir_id))
                    ir_obj.users.add(new_user_profile)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))



//template
<form action="{% url 'add_users' ir_id %}" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
                    {{add_user_formset.management_form}}
                    {% for item in add_user_formset%}
                        <tr>
                            <td><div>{{item.first_name}}</div></td>
                            <td><div>{{item.last_name}}</div></td>
                            <td><div>{{item.email}}</div></td>
                            <td><div>{{item.password1}}</div></td>
                            <td><div>{{item.password2}}</div></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create account">
                    </form>





//JavaScript

    $(document).on("click", ".irStatus-add-another-user", function () {
    var count = parseInt($('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val())
    var newRow = $('.add-users-table tbody tr:last').clone(true)

    newRow.find(':input').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (count-1) + '-','-' + (count) + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr('id', id);
        $(this).attr('name', name);
        $(this).val('');
    })
    newRow.appendTo('.add-users-table tbody')
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(''+(count+1))
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment your `<form>-TOTAL_FORMS` field from your management form by java script as well when you add a new form, as the formset uses this field to determine the amount of forms provided.
[Formset Management Form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)